# Table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it (stopping an average grade from dropping below 2.5)

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Here's the problem:

Create a trigger that prevents any change to the taking relation that would drop the overall average grade in any particular class below 2.5. Note: This trigger is not intended to address the average GPA of any given student, but rather it should address the average grade for all grades assigned in a particular class.

Here's the schema:

```
Student-schema =(studentnum, name, standing, gpa, major)
Class-schema = (schedulenum, semester, department, classnum, days, time, place, enrollment)
Instructor-schema = (name, department, office)
Teaches-schema = (name, schedulenum, semester)
Taking-schema = (studentnum, schedulenum, semester, grade)
```

I'm having a terrible time with these triggers, but here's my attempt to make this work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER stopChange
    AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT OR DELETE ON taking
    REFERENCING OLD AS old
    NEW AS new
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

grd_avg taking.grade%TYPE;

BEGIN
    SELECT AVG(grade)
    INTO grd_avg
    FROM taking
    WHERE studentnum = :new.studentnum
    AND schedulenum = :new.schedulenum
    AND semester = :new.semester;

    IF grd_avg < 2.5 THEN
        UPDATE taking
        SET grade = :old.grade
        WHERE studentnum = :old.studentnum
        AND schedulenum = :old.schedulenum
        AND semester = :old.semester;
    END IF;

END;   
/
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong because when I then go to update or delete a tuple, I get the error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table TAKING is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "STOPCHANGE", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'STOPCHANGE'
```

Any advice?  I'm using Oracle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can fix this by rewriting this as a *before* trigger, rather than an *after* trigger.  However, this might be a little complicated for inserts and deletes.  The idea is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER stopChange
    BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT OR DELETE ON taking
    REFERENCING OLD AS old
    NEW AS new
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

grd_avg taking.grade%TYPE;

BEGIN
    SELECT (SUM(grade) - oldgrade + new.grade) / count(*)
    INTO grd_avg
    FROM taking
    WHERE studentnum = :new.studentnum
    AND schedulenum = :new.schedulenum
    AND semester = :new.semester;

    IF grd_avg < 2.5 THEN
        new.grade = old.grade
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried this, and get the same error.  I wonder if my grade average is being calculated correctly and if I need to do some "elsif" statement to continue changing the update/insert/delete should it be above 2.5.  I'm lost. lol

Comment: Ok, here's what I've deduced.  You cannot do a select query inside of the pl/sql for a trigger when the table could be changed.  I wonder if I can rewrite this without using pl/sql.

Comment: @TheRationalist . . . As a matter of practice, I wrap inserts/updates/deletes into stored proceduers, rather than relying on triggers.  I think the problem is the *after* in the trigger (which I changed in my mind but not in the code apparantly).  I also changed the logic so it will work in the `update` case -- you might get a divide by 0 in a delete so the actual logic is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Hi , I am getting the same error now. When I am trying to insert one Entity object in database trigger is working fine. But when I am tring to insert multiple rows(Entity objects) then it is throwing the above error "table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it". We have used trigger just to update one column IS_LATEST as 'Y' or 'N'  when a new ID is added into database. Could someone help me here.

Answer (score 16):

First you need to read about triggers, mutating table error and compound triggers: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS2005

Your trigger is AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT OR DELETE. Means if you run UPDATE OR INSERT OR DELETE statements on this table, the trigger will fire. But you are trying to update the same table again inside your trigger, which is compl. wrong. This this is why you are getting the error. You cannot modify the same table the trigger is firing on. The purpose of trigger is to fire automatically when table is updated, inserted or deleted in your case. What you need is some procedure, not trigger.

Comment: Exactly to the point - "What you need is some procedure, not trigger."

Comment: Well, if you want to perform some kind of "data integrity checking" on a table, you can use a trigger without writing a procedure. But write a compound trigger. For each row: store, in an array, defined locally in your trigger's code, the ID of the inserted/modified (/deleted) record. After statement: do the "checking", not on the whole table, but on the IDs of the inserted/modified (/deleted) records, so that it's fast. If something is incorrect: raise an exception, so the data is "rollbacked" to its previous state. And don't forget to cleanup your array, before statement, or after statement.

Answer (score 16):

use this statement inside `DECLARE`, it will work.

```
pragma autonomous_transaction;
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me. For others that passed by the same problem to understand why this happen:

ORA-04091

Cause: A trigger (or a user defined PL/SQL function that is referenced in this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.

Action: Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e2100.htm#1002387

Comment: This will suppress the error but the trigger may still fail to run correctly like it happened in my case.

Comment: I agree with @RaymondWachaga: this will hide the error and create inconsistencies in data.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I noticed that if you do a select on the same table you put the trigger on you may/will get this problem.
You can remove **FOR EACH ROW** 
or use the data in **:New** to do the calculation (if possible) and then make the update.

In your case it will make more sense to use separate table to have the avg_grade per semester.

Answer (score 2):

Even we have ended up with same issue in our project. But after searching in few oracle forums, we have found the below solution.

1)Save the Old/New Column data in a temporary table as pat of row level trigger.
2) Write a statement level trigger and use the data saved in step 1.

This would solve the issue I think.

Comment: You're right. And if you want to "revert" your data to is previous state (which seems to be the aim in writing:        UPDATE taking
        SET grade = :old.grade
        WHERE studentnum = :old.studentnum
        AND schedulenum = :old.schedulenum
        AND semester = :old.semester;)   then raise simply an exception, for the transaction to fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want retrieve other data by join other table(TABLE_ADDRESS). Here is my solution.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_TABLE_ACTIVITIES AFTER  INSERT ON TABLE_NAME
     FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE 
    V_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(100); 
    BEGIN 

            SELECT A.ADDRESS INTO V_ADDRESS 
            FROM TABLE_ADDRESS A
            WHERE A.ADDRESSID = :NEW.ADDRESSID
            ;
            INSERT INTO TABLE_ACTIVITIES(
                            NAME, ADDRESS)
            VALUES(:NEW.NAME, V_ADDRESS);
    END;
    /
```