# How can i fix my trigger to automatically determine if first donation and update single column

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, triggers

I've hit a wall trying to create a trigger for my table.
I have a donation table that has a column (first_donation) that is checked 'Y' or 'N' depending whether it is a donor's first donation or not. I want to automate this process with a trigger that automatically adds the 'Y' or 'N' if a new donation is added. So if a donor submits a new donation or it is their first donation the column (first_donation) is adjusted to reflect Y or N. My first attempt at triggers and it did not seem too daunting at first and the language seemed easier than my last book on Java Script. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FIRST_DONATION_TG
      AFTER 
      INSERT OF donation_id  --id of donation pledge
      ON tt_donate
      FOR EACH ROW   
   BEGIN
      IF INSERTING THEN
      UPDATE tt_donation
      SET first_donation := 'Y';
      ELSE 
      SET first_donation := 'N';
   END IF;
   END FIRST_DONATION_TG;
```

Comment: Any errors? What is the actual problem? Also, some insight in the table structure might help. Some free info upfront: you shouldn't insert a new row inside an insert trigger (if it would work, it would keep inserting new rows indefinately!). And of course there is the [trigger may not see it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182089/table-is-mutating-trigger-function-may-not-see-it-stopping-an-average-grade-fr) issue when you try to query a table inside one of its triggers.

Comment: There are a few syntax errors (`nextval(newNum_seq)` should be `newNum_seq.nextval`).  Once we fix those, however, it doesn't makes sense to have hard-coded `amt_donated` and `date` values in the trigger.  Once we fix those issues, though, if this were to work you'd get an infinite loop as the trigger fired, inserting a row, firing the trigger, inserting a row... If your real intention is to look for other rows in `tt_donate`with the `:new.id_donor` value, a trigger is probably not the right approach.  You want a procedure that queries the table and does the insert.

Comment: Made some changes to the code and appreciate the comments and guidance where to improve or look. Didn't want to keep inserting new rows. My trigger should find the rows that are first payments that do not have the 'Y' or 'N' and change them accordingly. It should also add  the Y or N to new pledges. How does what I have re-written look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you'll find a working example what should do what you are loking for. I don't explain the details of the basic trigger syntax as you can read those from the fine manual: [PL/SQL Triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS020).

`before insert` trigger allows you to modify the inserted values before the row is inserted into the table (note the use of `:new` pseudorecord that gives access to the row-to-be-inserted). So here we will peek the table if the donor has made donations or not and then adjust the flag value. Note that at this point the table doesn't have the row we're going to insert.

Please also note the example table constraints that guard your data always has valid values.

**Example table**

```
create table donation (
 donator_id number not null
,amount number not null check(amount > 0)
,first_ varchar2(1) not null check(first_ in ('Y', 'N'))
,date_ date default sysdate not null
);

-- ensure searching donators is effective
create index donation_idx1 on donation(donator_id);
```

**Trigger**

```
create or replace trigger donation_trg1
before insert on donation
for each row
declare
  v_first_exists number;
begin
  -- check if a donator has made a donation
  select count(*) into v_first_exists
  from donation
  where donator_id = :new.donator_id
  -- we're only interested if a donation exists therefore
  -- we don't need to count beyond 1
  and rownum = 1;

  -- adjust the value before database inserts the row
  :new.first_ :=
    case
      when v_first_exists = 0 then 'Y'
      else 'N'
    end;
end;
/
```

**Example run**

```
insert into donation(donator_id, amount) values(1, 10);
insert into donation(donator_id, amount) values(1, 20);
insert into donation(donator_id, amount) values(1, 30);
insert into donation(donator_id, amount) values(2, 10);
insert into donation(donator_id, amount) values(2, 20);
insert into donation(donator_id, amount) values(2, 30);

select * from donation;

DONATOR_ID     AMOUNT FIRST_ DATE_
---------- ---------- ------ -------------------
         1         10 Y      2015-07-22 09:20.10
         1         20 N      2015-07-22 09:20.10
         1         30 N      2015-07-22 09:20.10
         2         10 Y      2015-07-22 09:20.10
         2         20 N      2015-07-22 09:20.10
         2         30 N      2015-07-22 09:20.10

 6 rows selected
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Excellent! I had to go back to the beginning chapters to refresh your use of CASE statements and the Oracle site for the check constraint which is fantastic. Why cannot someone write a book or tutorial that walks a beginner through the steps or processes why a certain decision/statement is made? My pseudo code looked pretty good. Much appreciated!

Comment: @allendks45 If you're serious about Oracle and PL/SQL I recommend Oracle's own PL/SQL documentation (available on-line for free) and Steve Feuerstein's  PL/SQL 101 articles (available on-line for free) and a book Oracle PL/SQL Programming, 5th Edition By Steven Feuerstein, Bill Pribyl. You'll find the links for all these resources from: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsql/info

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a homework assignment, I highly recommend *not* making data like this a part of the table data. That is, an indicator for each row that signifies its relationship with other rows.

What if the "first donation" entry was missed, not entered until after several subsequent donations were entered?

What if the "first donation" entry was entered incorrectly -- the date was wrong and the corrected date now places it after one or more donations? Or conversely, the corrected date of a subsequent donation now places it first?

There are a lot of "what ifs" that can be played here, each one illustrating how the data can go bad, causing you to have to analyse and correct what is now bad data -- after, that is, someone, possibly a customer, generates a report complaining of incorrect data.

A method less susceptible to changes in the underlying data is a view or two. One view would display only the first donations of each donor. That would probably satisfy whatever part of your app that is concerned with only the first donations.

Another view could be one that partitions over each donor generating row numbers (ordered by donation date). The first donation is row 1 of each group. A case statement can generate the 'Y' and 'N' as appropriate.

Now, no tricky triggers are needed and no matter how the underlying data is manipulated, changing the order perhaps of the donations, the next query will generate the correct results.

Your job gets a whole lot easier *and* you guarantee the correct results according to the current state of the data. What more could you ask for?

Comment: Actually this is a problem asked from the book I'm using trying to learn PL/SQL. From what @ user272735 advised, those resources are much more geared towards teaching/learning at a beginner pace. As a beginner I have to put some trust in more advanced programmers like yourself. Why does teaching a complex topic have to be so difficult? Is there a reason for not showing beginners the right and why way of coding? Maybe it is a bit of protecting the skill few understand. Appreciate your comment though!

Comment: Learning a complex topic is difficult enough. Some lessons make it even more so. I think many lessons are taught and textbooks written by PhD eggheads who have no or very limited real-world experience.