# Trigger Code returns 'Mutating' error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Learning triggers, and try to do a basic task where i am inserting a single data entry into a table called xml_hours_load_2 after i perform an insert statement into another table called xml_hours_load. However, after i try the insert statement into xml_hours_load, **i receive an error that reads:**
*SQL Error: ORA-04091: table XML_HOURS_LOAD is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "TEST_TRIGGER", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TEST_TRIGGER'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.*

Below is my trigger code and my insert statement:

```
create or replace TRIGGER test_trigger
AFTER INSERT
ON xml_hours_load
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
varROW_ID Varchar(50);

BEGIN
SELECT row_id INTO varROW_ID
from xml_hours_load;

INSERT INTO xml_hours_load_2
VALUES(varROW_ID, '2', '3', '5', '6', 'hi');
END;

insert into xml_hours_load(product_number, code, 
product_name, product_version, contact)
values('5', 'hello', 'no', '1', 'technical');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it (stopping an average grade from dropping below 2.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182089/table-is-mutating-trigger-function-may-not-see-it-stopping-an-average-grade-fr)

Comment: no thats not my question

Comment: Have you read all answers? Did you read the documentation about the triggers in a provided answer? Your code is wrong because you are doing a select (without any filters) in the same table you are inserting that's the origin of the error. The error description is pretty straight forward. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS770

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.  The trigger needs to be rewritten as

```
create or replace TRIGGER test_trigger
AFTER INSERT
ON xml_hours_load
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.ROW_ID IS NOT NULL)
    DECLARE

    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO xml_hours_load_2
    VALUES(:new.row_id, '2', '3', '5', '6', 'hi');
    END;
```

The :new value is the value which is modified in table xml_hours_load

Comment: what happens if i need to call another column from xml_hours_load into xml_hours_load_2? for example :    INSERT INTO xml_hours_load_2
    VALUES(:new.row_id,  column_name, '3', '5', '6', 'hi');

Comment: Is the column_name from xml_hours_load newly inserted for which the trigger has been raised. Then you can give it as :new.column_name.

:new is the new value inserted into xml_hours_load

Comment: thanks so much. upvoted and selected as best answer!

Comment: sorry one more thing, if i want to add a 'CASE statement' in front of the insert how would i do that? is this possible? Or would I now have to define variables? What i did was below but not sure if correct......create or replace TRIGGER test_trigger
AFTER INSERT
ON xml_hours_load
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

BEGIN
  CASE WHEN xml_hours_load.row_id is not null
  THEN
 INSERT INTO xml_hours_load_2
 VALUES(:new.ROW_ID, :new.product_number, '3', '5', '6', 'hi');
END;

Comment: I have edited my code above. So with this code.. The record gets inserted into xml_hours_load but not into xml_hours_load_2 when row_id is null

Comment: if i want to add to this trigger and insert different data based off different conditional (when/if) statements, would it be better i just create separate triggers then? Sorry, I know i already marked your question as the best and this question is probably out of scope of the original question so if you want me to create another question i can. ..

Comment: It would be better if you work on the same trigger if you are using the same tables.. You can have multiple triggers on the table xml_hours_load but cannot have multiple triggers inserting into xml_hours_load_2 for the same DML statement. Because we do not commit the trigger we commit the underlying DML statement.. So when we commit the DML on xml_hours_load then the xml_hours_load_2 gets committed. If you post another question you might get different responses which might be useful to you and others as well. Plz try to post the question with examples & result example which shows what you want

Comment: what if i wanted to load some columns (from xml_hours_load_2) into another table theoretically called xml_hours_load_3?

Comment: Not sure what you wanted to achieve but.. if you wanted to create a trigger to insert into xml_hours_load_3 for the trigger fired on xml_hours_load_2, you can certainly do that.. So when you insert a record in xml_hours_load it will insert records into xml_hours_load_2 and xml_hours_load_3 based on the triggers.